# Conflict between declaring instance variable and property

Tags: objective-c

I am studying Objective-C. I asked a question about this code earlier but I came up with further questions. The below code is trying to make `NSArray` externally but really makes `NSMutableArray` internally so I can add pointers or remove in `NSMutableArray`

I face two questions. 
1) What is the purpose of doing like this? Is there a specific reason you make `NSArray` externally? Why can't I just declare a property of `NSMutableArray`?

2)I learn that instance variable (`_assets`) is made when I declare a property of `NSArray *assets`. And I also declared `NSMutableArray *_assets` under the interface. I think those two `_assets` conflict each other even though they have different types. Am I thinking this in a wrong way?

```
@interface BNREmployee : BNRPerson
    {
        NSMutableArray *_assets;
    }

@property (nonatomic) unsigned int employeeID;
@property (nonatomic) unsigned int officeAlarmCode;
@property (nonatomic) NSDate *hireDate;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *assets;
```

Comment: Only provide the public property if other classes need to access it. And you can make the property have a type of `NSMutableArray` if you need to. But that, combined with `copy` is tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try put your answers the way you have asked them. Let hope they clear your doubts. By now I guess you would be knowing that `NSArray` once initialised with data you wont be able to add or delete the data inside it which is different from `NSMutableArray`.

The benefit here no one else can change your externally visible data. Also when you try to sort or iterate the array you are sure that no other data would be removed or added. Also if you use `NSMutableArray` for such cases the application would crash if you add data while you iterate the array.

Like @KirkSpaziani Explained

```
@synthesize assets = _assets;
```

would create an instance variable for your property. However you are actually supposed to use this `_assets` only in getter and setter. Else places you should be using `self.assets`.

You can also synthesize your other array `NSMutableArray *_assets` as follows

`@synthesize _assets = __assets;`
Which would have double underscore, but frankly we shouldn't be using the underscore for a starting variable name. Plus would be great if you have different names altogether.

Also with advances in Objective C you dont require to synthesize these variables at all. Just use the `self.variableName` and you can access it.

Hope it clears some of your queries.

Answer (score 1):

Put
    {
        NSMutableArray *_assets;
    }
in the @implementation block

```
@implementation {
   NSMutableArray *_assets;
}
```

Putting the NSMutableArray in the implementation block hides the fact that it is mutable from consumers (it is no longer in the header file).

Follow it with:

```
@synthesize assets = _assets;
```

This might not be necessary actually, but makes things clearer.  When you declare a property an ivar will be automatically created (unless you @dynamic the property).  However an explicitly declared ivar of the same name will override the automatically created one - so long as the type is the same or a subclass.

The reason to make it an NSArray publicly visible is so that no one else can mutate your data structure.  You will have control of it.  If it is an NSMutableArray internally then you can add and remove items without exposing that functionality to consumers.

You can declare your property to be readonly or readwrite - a readwrite NSArray means you can replace the whole array with a property set, but you can't add or remove items.  If internally you are adding and removing items, this can make things messy.  Try to stick with readonly when having a mutable internal version.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something you can do if you want `_assets` to be a mutable array, but you don't want other classes to modify it, implement the setter and getter of the assets property so they look like this (implementing the getter and the setter will cause the property to not be synthesised, which means the `NSArray *_assets` will not be created automatically):

```
-(NSArray *)assets{
  return [_assets copy]; // Copy creates an immutable copy
}
-(void)setAssets:(NSArray *)assets{
  _assets = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:assets];
}
```

Keep in mind that if you access the assets array a LOT, it might be slow since you're creating an immutable copy every time, so you can create an NSArray whenever your `_assets` array is modified and return that in the `-(NSArray *)assets` method

Answer (score 0):

The reason you'd internally keep an `NSMutableArray`, but expose an `NSArray` externally is so that users of your API won't abuse it and mutate its data. Keeping it visible as immutable makes people less prone to mess with it.

Another approach you could take to this is to not use a property at all, but simply have a getter and a mutable property in a class extension. For example, in your .h:

```
@interface BNREmployee : BNRPerson

- (NSArray *)assets;

@end
```

In your .m

```
@interface BNREmployee ()

// Inside of the class manipulate this property
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *mutableAssets;

@end

@implementation BNREmployee

// Clients of your class rely on this
- (NSArray *)assets
{
    // copy makes the result immutable
    return [self.mutableAssets copy];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach might be to make the property only writable to the implementation of you class.

To do that you declare your property as `readonly` in the header:

```
//BNREmployee.h
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSMutableArray *assets;
```

Than declare it as `readwrite` inside an inner interface in your implementation:

```
//BNREmployee.m
@interface BNREmployee()
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSMutableArray *assets;
@end

@implementation
...
```